# How to define array of objects in a properties file and read from Java program

Tags: java, properties

I have a properties file like this.

```
property[0].name=A
property[0].value=1
property[1].name=B
property[1].value=2
property[2].name=C
property[2].value=3
```

How to read this file as a list of objects of a class {name, value} in plain java program using ResourceBundle or Properties?

Here is the class.

```
public class XYZ {
  private String name;
  private String value;
  // Getters & Setters
}
```

I need to get like this.

```
ArrayList<XYZ> propertiesList = SomeUtility.getProperties("property", XYZ.class);
```

Utility class might be like this.

```
public class SomeUtility {
  public static ArrayList getProperties(String key, Class cls) {
    //logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you read it as a simple file?

Comment: I can read as a text file, but dont want to do manual parsing. Looing for any pre-defined util or method already out there?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to manually parse it?

Comment: If I manually parse it, I have to define list size (here its 3). But if it parses in built I can add more values to the properties and it reflects on the outcome. I know there are ways to achieve this, but want a cleaner implementation. Like @PropertySource from Spring.

Comment: I've provided a very simple way of reading a properties file, let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand exactly what you want so feel free to correct me and give me more constraints to work with but here is a simple way to read a `Properties` file located somewhere in your project:

```
private static void readPropertiesFile(String path) throws IOException {

    java.util.Map<String, String> map = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    properties.load(inputStream);

    for (String name : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        map.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));
    }
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("Property Key: %s, Property Value: %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Property Key: property[0].name, Property Value: A
Property Key: property[1].name, Property Value: B
Property Key: property[0].value, Property Value: 1
Property Key: property[1].value, Property Value: 2
Property Key: property[2].name, Property Value: C
Property Key: property[2].value, Property Value: 3
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew... But this is not what I am looking for. Need to converting this properties file into ArrayList<XYZ> where XYZ is a class of {name, value}.

Comment: Is this class defined somewhere? All I see is numbers and letters in your sample.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you provided the whole properties file so I have something tangible to work with.

Comment: Edited the problem summary. Please check.

Comment: Can you explain exactly why just using `java.util.Properties` isn't enough? Why do you have to involve classes into this? You can load your properties file and then do with it what ever you want i.e. place it in a map or a dedicated data wrapper class object.

Comment: If you can better explain what exactly you want to accomplish (as in whats the purpose of creating an `ArrayList` of these properties that **HAS** to be extracted with a special utility) I can provide a better answer. But as it stands I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: Posted what I want to achieve as an answer .

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I wrote, but it involves Reflect and Gson. Is there any better way to do this? Anything already available which is fine tuned like Apache's.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

public class ListResourceBundle {

    public static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    private final ResourceBundle bundle;

    public ListResourceBundle(ResourceBundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    public List<?> getProperties(String key, Class<?> cls) {
        final int maxArraySize = getMaxArraySize(key, getMatchingKeys(key));
        final List<String> fields = getFields(cls);

        final List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxArraySize; i++) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            for (String field : fields) {
                jsonObject.addProperty(field, getStringOrNull(key + "[" + i + "]." + field));
            }

            result.add(gson.fromJson(jsonObject, cls));
        }

        System.out.println("result.toString() = " + result.toString());
        return result;
    }

    public List<String> getMatchingKeys(String key) {
        Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
        List<String> matchingKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String k = keys.nextElement();
            if(k.startsWith(key)) {
                matchingKeys.add(k);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(matchingKeys);
        return matchingKeys;
    }

    public int getMaxArraySize(String key, List<String> matchingKeys) {
        int maxArraySize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            boolean indexAvailable = false;
            for (String matchingKey : matchingKeys) {
                if(matchingKey.startsWith(key + "[" + i + "]")) {
                    indexAvailable = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(indexAvailable) {
                maxArraySize++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return maxArraySize;
    }

    public String getStringOrNull(String key) {
        try {
            return bundle.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getFields(Class<?> cls) {
        final List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
            fields.add(field.getName());
        }
        return fields;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.application.resources.Resource");
        ListResourceBundle applicationResourceBundle = new ListResourceBundle(bundle);
        applicationResourceBundle.getProperties("property", ReportParam.class);
    }

}
```

Resource:

```
property[0].name=A
property[0].value=1
property[1].name=B
property[1].value=2
property[2].name=C
property[2].value=3
```

Output:

```
result.toString() = [
ReportParam{name='A', value='1'}, 
ReportParam{name='B', value='2'}, 
ReportParam{name='C', value='3'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: property[0].url[0].name="ABC"
property[0].url[0].value="abc.com"
I have further nested object. How should i make the above function generic ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use JSON:

in your file:
`property=[{"name":"A","value":"1"},{"name":"B","value":"2"},{"name":"C","value":"3"}]`

and then deserialize it using `com.google.gson.gson` (or any other) library:
`ArrayList<XYZ> propertiesList;`
`propertiesList = new gsonbuilder().create().fromjson(property, propertiesList.class);`

**NOTE**: I haven't tested this code, and i'm not very familiar with java so i am sure there is a better,cleaner way to implement this.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's bit late of an answer, but if I understand your problem statement correctly, you can use :

> `@ConfigurationProperties`

to get your job done.
Here is my spring-boot example with a YAML file for the sake of convenience (same can be achieved through properties file as well).

**application.yaml:**

```
xyz:
 xyzprops :
 -
  name: cbc
  value: 441
 - 
  name: obc
  value: 443
```

**XYZ class:**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "xyz")
public class XYZ{
    private List<XYZProps> xyzprops;

    public List<XYZProps> getXyzprops() {
        return xyzprops;
    }

    public void setXyzprops(List<XYZProps> xyzprops) {
        this.xyzprops = xyzprops;
    }
    
    public class XYZProps{
        String name;
        String value;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then @Autowire XYZ where you want to use it.